# updating contents of stylesheet with .innerText slow

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet

I have a stylesheet I'm updating the contents of on the fly, based on a user UI. I noticed that in Firefox ( which uses stylesheet.innerHTML ) and IE ( which uses stylesheet.styleSheet.cssText) works well.

It seems that Chrome and Safari ( which use stylesheet.innerText ) run incredibly slow on larger stylesheets. Has anyone run into this and/or found better solutions?

**EDIT:**
It's not possible to use JS to change inline styles since the application never refreshes and the user can switch "pages" thereby nuking the inline styles. Also if I want to use the UI to modify links, I can't use inline to modify pseudo classes such as :hover ( as far as I know )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So this has been my function for updating stylesheets for the past year or so:

```
function(style, style_value) {

  if ('cssText' in style.styleSheet) {

    // without this line, IE WILL crash, if no stylesheet settings were set
    if ( typeof(style_value) != 'string' || !style_value.length) {
      return;
    }
    style.styleSheet.cssText = style_value;

  }
  else {
    style.innerHTML = style_value;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes the sense that reparsing CSS and reflowing the document could be slow.  I suggest including all rules you could need but "namespace" them with a class on the `<html>` element and then change the active rules by adding and removing classes rather than using using cssText/innerText.

CSS:

```
.foo h1 { color: green }
.bar h1 { color: red }
```

JavaScript:

```
document.documentElement.className = new Date().getHours() >= 12 ? 'foo' : 'bar';
```

This would clobber any other class names on the `<html>` element so more careful parsing or toggling classes via jQuery (or equivalent) would generally be appropriate.

If your JavaScript knows what CSS rules actually need to change you could also modify the style rules on the fly.  In practice, this is similar to modifying any elements style i.e. `myElement.style.color = 'green';`  Opera web curriculum has a [good explanation of modifying CSS via JavaScript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/dynamic-style-css-javascript/).

Example of cross-browser method to modify a single rule:

```
var modifyStyleRule;

(function(doc){
    var sheets = doc.styleSheets,
        rules = 'cssRules';
    rules = sheets[0][rules] ? rules : 'rules';

    modifyStyleRule = function (sheetIndex, ruleIndex, propertyValues) {
        var style = sheets[sheetIndex][rules][ruleIndex].style,
            prop;

        for (prop in propertyValues) {
            if (propertyValues.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                style[prop] = propertyValues[prop];
            }
        }
    };
})(document);
```

Example usage: `modifyStyleRule(0, 0, {color: 'red'});`.

Note that depending on the type and amount of changes you make with this (colors vs size/position) this could *very easily be slower* than `sheet.innerHTML` or equivalent.  This technique does come in handy from time to time and when combined with "style namespaces" and swapping class names, large changes can be still be performant.

Comment: By using more classes I could get away with most options - such as changing a class for bold vs nonbold or italic or not... but Not sure if I could adapt it to change RGB colors. I edited above to answer for any other future posters as to why el.style is not usable in this case.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting el.style for your question rather modifying the "global" css rules.  There are examples in that Opera link but a quick and dirty non-IE example would be `document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].style.color = 'blue';` which could change the "global" `a:visited` color (if that's the right stylesheet and rule of course).

Comment: Just checked up the article on the other methods of editing aside from style.rule. I don't see the .rules way and I tried in Chrome with no luck. Sorry if I'm missing something after a long day.

I'm looking at insertRule and those methods in the article now... they are working fine but I can't seem to get the modified information from innerText. That problem is secondary but I'd love to be able to save off the CSS sheet after modifying for use at a later time.

Comment: Added example of cross-browser method to modify CSS rules.  That Opera article does show this sort of thing but it's actually buried in the example pages, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it browser independent use this code:

```
var field = document.getElementById(id);  // where u want to use innertext

if(field != null)
{           
    if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") // appName for both FireFox and Chrome its is "Netscape" i checked it with different version.
        field.textContent = value;
    else // for For IE v 8 i checked  .textContent is not supported by IE for me it was not working. 
        field.innerText = value;    
}
```

Comment: Since I'm using jQuery there is no need to use navigator. They handle that bit for me.